# How to prevent timed out waiting for eval response when using rbtrace with Rails 4 locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

So I'm running a Rails 4 application (an API) locally with a process id of 11697.  I have the following setup, yet I get the following response via the bash command I issue:

```
*** run `sudo sysctl kernel.msgmnb=1048576` to prevent losing events (currently: 16384 bytes)
*** attached to process 11697
*** timed out waiting for eval response
*** detached from process 11697
```

It doesn't seem to wait 600 seconds before timing out.  [I've seen this PR on github, so it seems like it should work](https://github.com/tmm1/rbtrace/issues/40).

The goal here is to take multiple heap snapshots of a Rails application's objects and compare the 2 diffs to try and detect a memory leak.

**config/environment.rb**

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
require 'rbtrace'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

**bash command prompt**

```
bundle exec rbtrace -p 11697 -e 'Thread.new{require "objspace"; ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations_start; GC.start(); ObjectSpace.dump_all(output: File.open("heap.json", "w"))}.join'  --timeout=600
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a different PR (42) was the one that was [actually merged](https://github.com/tmm1/rbtrace/pull/42) on Jun 14 to solve this issue and that they haven't made a release of `rbtrace` since [February 13th](https://github.com/tmm1/rbtrace/releases)

So the code is merged into master, but it hasn't been released via rubygems.org.

You can add the `rbtrace` gem's master branch as a dependency in your gemfile like the example below. You would have the PR code that enabled the timeout option for `eval`, but the `master` branch may not be completely ready for production use. Use at your own risk!

```
gem 'rbtrace', git: 'https://github.com/tmm1/rbtrace', branch: 'master'
```